# jqplot format tooltip values

Tags: hover, tooltip, jqplot, format-string, jqplot-highlighter

I want to have a tooltip hover highlight thingy in jqplot. The problem is that I want it to give more detail then on the axes. So the formatter should be different. I can't get it to display the seconds to:

There's a JS fidle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DWFTb/12/)!

I want the timestamp to display as hours:minutes:seconds, which would be format string '%H:%M:%S' or '%T' or '%X'. But how do I do that?

```
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 3,
        //useAxesFormatters: false,
        //tooltipFormatString: '%H:%M:%S',
        formatString: '<table class="jqplot-highlighter"><tr><td>tijd:</td><td>%s</td></tr><tr><td>snelheid:</td><td>%s</td></tr></table>',
    },
```

Comment: hi, did you find a solution. I need exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question is old, but I was looking for the same and there is an options (even in the version used here) to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/DWFTb/151/

```
highlighter: {
    show: true,
    sizeAdjust: 3,
    tooltipContentEditor: function(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, jqPlot) {

        return series[seriesIndex][pointIndex][0];

    }
}...
```

I hope this help others.

Comment: Hey Coma, thank you very much for digging this up. Stupid highlight has been annoying me forever. Finaly an easy way to get the data and return HTML to the highlighter container!

Comment: I wonder why this wasn't in the API (or if it was, it was super hard to find). Coma saved my life with this!

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for same question, unfortunately no answer yet. The ugly solution that I came with is, modify the jqplot.highlighter.js to get what I wanted. Here is how, I accomplished this,

Declare xAxisFormatString and yAxisFormatString properties

```js
// prop: xAxisFormatString
// If this is provided then it will override the axesformatter format string
this.xAxisFormatString = '';
// prop: xAxisFormatString
// If this is provided then it will override the axesformatter format string
this.yAxisFormatString = '';
```

Then at showtooltip method use this instead of axes format string

```js
var xfstr = series._xaxis._ticks[0].formatString;
if('' != hl.xAxisFormatString) {
    xfstr = hl.xAxisFormatString;
}
var yfstr = series._yaxis._ticks[0].formatString;
if('' != hl.yAxisFormatString) {
    yfstr = hl.yAxisFormatString;
}
```

When calling the graph,

```js
highlighter: {
    show: true,
    useAxesFormatters: true,
    xAxisFormatString: '%m-%Y',
    formatString: 'hi - %s',
    sizeAdjust: 7.5
},
```

I have the useAxesFormatters true because i don't want to mess with the tooltipformatstring. I am okay to use the same formatter but I would like to override the formatstring. this way I got it working.

Here is the complete jqplot.highlighter.js

```js
/**
* jqPlot
* Pure JavaScript plotting plugin using jQuery
*
* Version: 1.0.0b2_r792
*
* Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Chris Leonello
* jqPlot is currently available for use in all personal or commercial projects 
* under both the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) and GPL 
* version 2.0 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html) licenses. This means that you can 
* choose the license that best suits your project and use it accordingly. 
*
* Although not required, the author would appreciate an email letting him 
* know of any substantial use of jqPlot.  You can reach the author at: 
* chris at jqplot dot com or see http://www.jqplot.com/info.php .
*
* If you are feeling kind and generous, consider supporting the project by
* making a donation at: http://www.jqplot.com/donate.php .
*
* sprintf functions contained in jqplot.sprintf.js by Ash Searle:
*
*     version 2007.04.27
*     author Ash Searle
*     http://hexmen.com/blog/2007/03/printf-sprintf/
*     http://hexmen.com/js/sprintf.js
*     The author (Ash Searle) has placed this code in the public domain:
*     "This code is unrestricted: you are free to use it however you like."
* 
*/
    (function($) {
    $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotMouseMove', handleMove]);

    /**
    * Class: $.jqplot.Highlighter
    * Plugin which will highlight data points when they are moused over.
    * 
    * To use this plugin, include the js
    * file in your source:
    * 
    * > <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>
    * 
    * A tooltip providing information about the data point is enabled by default.
    * To disable the tooltip, set "showTooltip" to false.
    * 
    * You can control what data is displayed in the tooltip with various
    * options.  The "tooltipAxes" option controls wether the x, y or both
    * data values are displayed.
    * 
    * Some chart types (e.g. hi-low-close) have more than one y value per
    * data point. To display the additional values in the tooltip, set the
    * "yvalues" option to the desired number of y values present (3 for a hlc chart).
    * 
    * By default, data values will be formatted with the same formatting
    * specifiers as used to format the axis ticks.  A custom format code
    * can be supplied with the tooltipFormatString option.  This will apply 
    * to all values in the tooltip.  
    * 
    * For more complete control, the "formatString" option can be set.  This
    * Allows conplete control over tooltip formatting.  Values are passed to
    * the format string in an order determined by the "tooltipAxes" and "yvalues"
    * options.  So, if you have a hi-low-close chart and you just want to display 
    * the hi-low-close values in the tooltip, you could set a formatString like:
    * 
    * > highlighter: {
    * >     tooltipAxes: 'y',
    * >     yvalues: 3,
    * >     formatString:'<table class="jqplot-highlighter">
    * >         <tr><td>hi:</td><td>%s</td></tr>
    * >         <tr><td>low:</td><td>%s</td></tr>
    * >         <tr><td>close:</td><td>%s</td></tr></table>'
    * > }
    * 
    */
$.jqplot.Highlighter = function(options) {
    // Group: Properties
    //
    //prop: show
    // true to show the highlight.
    this.show = $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins;
    // prop: markerRenderer
    // Renderer used to draw the marker of the highlighted point.
    // Renderer will assimilate attributes from the data point being highlighted,
    // so no attributes need set on the renderer directly.
    // Default is to turn off shadow drawing on the highlighted point.
    this.markerRenderer = new $.jqplot.MarkerRenderer({shadow:false});
    // prop: showMarker
    // true to show the marker
    this.showMarker  = true;
    // prop: lineWidthAdjust
    // Pixels to add to the lineWidth of the highlight.
    this.lineWidthAdjust = 2.5;
    // prop: sizeAdjust
    // Pixels to add to the overall size of the highlight.
    this.sizeAdjust = 5;
    // prop: showTooltip
    // Show a tooltip with data point values.
    this.showTooltip = true;
    // prop: tooltipLocation
    // Where to position tooltip, 'n', 'ne', 'e', 'se', 's', 'sw', 'w', 'nw'
    this.tooltipLocation = 'nw';
    // prop: fadeTooltip
    // true = fade in/out tooltip, flase = show/hide tooltip
    this.fadeTooltip = true;
    // prop: tooltipFadeSpeed
    // 'slow', 'def', 'fast', or number of milliseconds.
    this.tooltipFadeSpeed = "fast";
    // prop: tooltipOffset
    // Pixel offset of tooltip from the highlight.
    this.tooltipOffset = 2;
    // prop: tooltipAxes
    // Which axes to display in tooltip, 'x', 'y' or 'both', 'xy' or 'yx'
    // 'both' and 'xy' are equivalent, 'yx' reverses order of labels.
    this.tooltipAxes = 'both';
    // prop; tooltipSeparator
    // String to use to separate x and y axes in tooltip.
    this.tooltipSeparator = ', ';
    // prop; tooltipContentEditor
    // Function used to edit/augment/replace the formatted tooltip contents.
    // Called as str = tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex)
    // where str is the generated tooltip html and seriesIndex and pointIndex identify
    // the data point being highlighted. Should return the html for the tooltip contents.
    this.tooltipContentEditor = null;
    // prop: useAxesFormatters
    // Use the x and y axes formatters to format the text in the tooltip.
    this.useAxesFormatters = true;
// prop: xAxisFormatString
// If this is provided then it will override the axesformatter format string
this.xAxisFormatString = '';
// prop: xAxisFormatString
// If this is provided then it will override the axesformatter format string
this.yAxisFormatString = '';
    // prop: tooltipFormatString
    // sprintf format string for the tooltip.
    // Uses Ash Searle's javascript sprintf implementation
    // found here: http://hexmen.com/blog/2007/03/printf-sprintf/
    // See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html for reference.
    // Additional "p" and "P" format specifiers added by Chris Leonello.
    this.tooltipFormatString = '%.5P';
    // prop: formatString
    // alternative to tooltipFormatString
    // will format the whole tooltip text, populating with x, y values as
    // indicated by tooltipAxes option.  So, you could have a tooltip like:
    // 'Date: %s, number of cats: %d' to format the whole tooltip at one go.
    // If useAxesFormatters is true, values will be formatted according to
    // Axes formatters and you can populate your tooltip string with 
    // %s placeholders.
    this.formatString = null;
    // prop: yvalues
    // Number of y values to expect in the data point array.
    // Typically this is 1.  Certain plots, like OHLC, will
    // have more y values in each data point array.
    this.yvalues = 1;
    // prop: bringSeriesToFront
    // This option requires jQuery 1.4+
    // True to bring the series of the highlighted point to the front
    // of other series.
    this.bringSeriesToFront = false;
    this._tooltipElem;
    this.isHighlighting = false;

    $.extend(true, this, options);
};

var locations = ['nw', 'n', 'ne', 'e', 'se', 's', 'sw', 'w'];
var locationIndicies = {'nw':0, 'n':1, 'ne':2, 'e':3, 'se':4, 's':5, 'sw':6, 'w':7};
var oppositeLocations = ['se', 's', 'sw', 'w', 'nw', 'n', 'ne', 'e'];

// axis.renderer.tickrenderer.formatter

// called with scope of plot
$.jqplot.Highlighter.init = function (target, data, opts){
    var options = opts || {};
    // add a highlighter attribute to the plot
    this.plugins.highlighter = new $.jqplot.Highlighter(options.highlighter);
};

// called within scope of series
$.jqplot.Highlighter.parseOptions = function (defaults, options) {
    // Add a showHighlight option to the series 
    // and set it to true by default.
    this.showHighlight = true;
};

// called within context of plot
// create a canvas which we can draw on.
// insert it before the eventCanvas, so eventCanvas will still capture events.
$.jqplot.Highlighter.postPlotDraw = function() {
    // Memory Leaks patch    
    if (this.plugins.highlighter && this.plugins.highlighter.highlightCanvas) {
        this.plugins.highlighter.highlightCanvas.resetCanvas();
        this.plugins.highlighter.highlightCanvas = null;
    }

    if (this.plugins.highlighter && this.plugins.highlighter._tooltipElem) {
        this.plugins.highlighter._tooltipElem.emptyForce();
        this.plugins.highlighter._tooltipElem = null;
    }

    this.plugins.highlighter.highlightCanvas = new $.jqplot.GenericCanvas();
    
    this.eventCanvas._elem.before(this.plugins.highlighter.highlightCanvas.createElement(this._gridPadding, 'jqplot-highlight-canvas', this._plotDimensions, this));
    this.plugins.highlighter.highlightCanvas.setContext();

    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    this.plugins.highlighter._tooltipElem = $(elem);
    elem = null;
    this.plugins.highlighter._tooltipElem.addClass('jqplot-highlighter-tooltip');
    this.plugins.highlighter._tooltipElem.css({position:'absolute', display:'none'});
    
    this.eventCanvas._elem.before(this.plugins.highlighter._tooltipElem);
};

$.jqplot.preInitHooks.push($.jqplot.Highlighter.init);
$.jqplot.preParseSeriesOptionsHooks.push($.jqplot.Highlighter.parseOptions);
$.jqplot.postDrawHooks.push($.jqplot.Highlighter.postPlotDraw);

function draw(plot, neighbor) {
    var hl = plot.plugins.highlighter;
    var s = plot.series[neighbor.seriesIndex];
    var smr = s.markerRenderer;
    var mr = hl.markerRenderer;
    mr.style = smr.style;
    mr.lineWidth = smr.lineWidth + hl.lineWidthAdjust;
    mr.size = smr.size + hl.sizeAdjust;
    var rgba = $.jqplot.getColorComponents(smr.color);
    var newrgb = [rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2]];
    var alpha = (rgba[3] >= 0.6) ? rgba[3]*0.6 : rgba[3]*(2-rgba[3]);
    mr.color = 'rgba('+newrgb[0]+','+newrgb[1]+','+newrgb[2]+','+alpha+')';
    mr.init();
    mr.draw(s.gridData[neighbor.pointIndex][0], s.gridData[neighbor.pointIndex][1], hl.highlightCanvas._ctx);
}

function showTooltip(plot, series, neighbor) {
    // neighbor looks like: {seriesIndex: i, pointIndex:j, gridData:p, data:s.data[j]}
    // gridData should be x,y pixel coords on the grid.
    // add the plot._gridPadding to that to get x,y in the target.
    var hl = plot.plugins.highlighter;
    var elem = hl._tooltipElem;
    if (hl.useAxesFormatters) {
        var xf = series._xaxis._ticks[0].formatter;
        var yf = series._yaxis._ticks[0].formatter;
        var xfstr = series._xaxis._ticks[0].formatString; 
    if('' != hl.xAxisFormatString)
    xfstr = hl.xAxisFormatString;
        var yfstr = series._yaxis._ticks[0].formatString;
    if('' != hl.yAxisFormatString)
    yfstr = hl.yAxisFormatString;
        var str;
        var xstr = xf(xfstr, neighbor.data[0]);
        var ystrs = [];
        for (var i=1; i<hl.yvalues+1; i++) {
            ystrs.push(yf(yfstr, neighbor.data[i]));
        }
        if (hl.formatString) {
            switch (hl.tooltipAxes) {
                case 'both':
                case 'xy':
                    ystrs.unshift(xstr);
                    ystrs.unshift(hl.formatString);
                    str = $.jqplot.sprintf.apply($.jqplot.sprintf, ystrs);
                    break;
                case 'yx':
                    ystrs.push(xstr);
                    ystrs.unshift(hl.formatString);
                    str = $.jqplot.sprintf.apply($.jqplot.sprintf, ystrs);
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    str = $.jqplot.sprintf.apply($.jqplot.sprintf, [hl.formatString, xstr]);
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    ystrs.unshift(hl.formatString);
                    str = $.jqplot.sprintf.apply($.jqplot.sprintf, ystrs);
                    break;
                default: // same as xy
                    ystrs.unshift(xstr);
                    ystrs.unshift(hl.formatString);
                    str = $.jqplot.sprintf.apply($.jqplot.sprintf, ystrs);
                    break;
            } 
        }
        else {
            switch (hl.tooltipAxes) {
                case 'both':
                case 'xy':
                    str = xstr;
                    for (var i=0; i<ystrs.length; i++) {
                        str += hl.tooltipSeparator + ystrs[i];
                    }
                    break;
                case 'yx':
                    str = '';
                    for (var i=0; i<ystrs.length; i++) {
                        str += ystrs[i] + hl.tooltipSeparator;
                    }
                    str += xstr;
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    str = xstr;
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    str = ystrs.join(hl.tooltipSeparator);
                    break;
                default: // same as 'xy'
                    str = xstr;
                    for (var i=0; i<ystrs.length; i++) {
                        str += hl.tooltipSeparator + ystrs[i];
                    }
                    break;
                
            }                
        }
    }
    else {
        var str;
        if (hl.tooltipAxes == 'both' || hl.tooltipAxes == 'xy') {
            str = $.jqplot.sprintf(hl.tooltipFormatString, neighbor.data[0]) + hl.tooltipSeparator + $.jqplot.sprintf(hl.tooltipFormatString, neighbor.data[1]);
        }
        else if (hl.tooltipAxes == 'yx') {
            str = $.jqplot.sprintf(hl.tooltipFormatString, neighbor.data[1]) + hl.tooltipSeparator + $.jqplot.sprintf(hl.tooltipFormatString, neighbor.data[0]);
        }
        else if (hl.tooltipAxes == 'x') {
            str = $.jqplot.sprintf(hl.tooltipFormatString, neighbor.data[0]);
        }
        else if (hl.tooltipAxes == 'y') {
            str = $.jqplot.sprintf(hl.tooltipFormatString, neighbor.data[1]);
        } 
    }
    if ($.isFunction(hl.tooltipContentEditor)) {
        // args str, seriesIndex, pointIndex are essential so the hook can look up
        // extra data for the point.
        str = hl.tooltipContentEditor(str, neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, plot);
    }
    elem.html(str);
    var gridpos = {x:neighbor.gridData[0], y:neighbor.gridData[1]};
    var ms = 0;
    var fact = 0.707;
    if (series.markerRenderer.show == true) { 
        ms = (series.markerRenderer.size + hl.sizeAdjust)/2;
    }
    
    var loc = locations;
    if (series.fillToZero && series.fill && neighbor.data[1] < 0) {
        loc = oppositeLocations;
    }
    
    switch (loc[locationIndicies[hl.tooltipLocation]]) {
        case 'nw':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left - elem.outerWidth(true) - hl.tooltipOffset - fact * ms;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top - hl.tooltipOffset - elem.outerHeight(true) - fact * ms;
            break;
        case 'n':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left - elem.outerWidth(true)/2;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top - hl.tooltipOffset - elem.outerHeight(true) - ms;
            break;
        case 'ne':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left + hl.tooltipOffset + fact * ms;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top - hl.tooltipOffset - elem.outerHeight(true) - fact * ms;
            break;
        case 'e':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left + hl.tooltipOffset + ms;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top - elem.outerHeight(true)/2;
            break;
        case 'se':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left + hl.tooltipOffset + fact * ms;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top + hl.tooltipOffset + fact * ms;
            break;
        case 's':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left - elem.outerWidth(true)/2;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top + hl.tooltipOffset + ms;
            break;
        case 'sw':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left - elem.outerWidth(true) - hl.tooltipOffset - fact * ms;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top + hl.tooltipOffset + fact * ms;
            break;
        case 'w':
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left - elem.outerWidth(true) - hl.tooltipOffset - ms;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top - elem.outerHeight(true)/2;
            break;
        default: // same as 'nw'
            var x = gridpos.x + plot._gridPadding.left - elem.outerWidth(true) - hl.tooltipOffset - fact * ms;
            var y = gridpos.y + plot._gridPadding.top - hl.tooltipOffset - elem.outerHeight(true) - fact * ms;
            break;
    }
    elem.css('left', x);
    elem.css('top', y);
    if (hl.fadeTooltip) {
        // Fix for stacked up animations.  Thnanks Trevor!
        elem.stop(true,true).fadeIn(hl.tooltipFadeSpeed);
    }
    else {
        elem.show();
    }
    elem = null;
    
}

function handleMove(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    var hl = plot.plugins.highlighter;
    var c = plot.plugins.cursor;
    if (hl.show) {
        if (neighbor == null && hl.isHighlighting) {
            var ctx = hl.highlightCanvas._ctx;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            if (hl.fadeTooltip) {
                hl._tooltipElem.fadeOut(hl.tooltipFadeSpeed);
            }
            else {
                hl._tooltipElem.hide();
            }
            if (hl.bringSeriesToFront) {
                plot.restorePreviousSeriesOrder();
            }
            hl.isHighlighting = false;
            ctx = null;
        
        }
        else if (neighbor != null && plot.series[neighbor.seriesIndex].showHighlight && !hl.isHighlighting) {
            hl.isHighlighting = true;
            if (hl.showMarker) {
                draw(plot, neighbor);
            }
            if (hl.showTooltip && (!c || !c._zoom.started)) {
                showTooltip(plot, plot.series[neighbor.seriesIndex], neighbor);
            }
            if (hl.bringSeriesToFront) {
                plot.moveSeriesToFront(neighbor.seriesIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Even I don't like to change the source code, then I have to maintain it when I upgrade. But your solution works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use [coma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522083/311976) but first modified it to:

```
return jqPlot.series[seriesIndex]._plotData[pointIndex][0];
```

which is a hack (because it uses _plotData) and then changed it to

```
return jqPlot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex][0];
```

which should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use highlighter you can quickly obtain wanted results by setting your format in `tickOptions` as the format the highlighter uses is taken from ticks.

Otherwise you must serve yourself the `jqplotMouseMove` event [as shown here.](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src/4f8bccac8cb9/examples/customHighlighterTooltip.html)

Comment: could you please explain your answer in detail. The mousemove event link is not working. Setting format in tickoption will change the axis format which we don't need. We need axis format to be different from highlighter format.

Comment: @Esen I believe I found the right link it was a while now. If I find a better example I will let you know ASAP.

Comment: Thanks @Boro, I think I will go with Senthilkumar solution. I hate to modify the source file then I need to remember that when I upgrade. But that works perfect for me.